# reactjs is not compatible with ie 11 in some scenarios

Tags: internet-explorer, reactjs

run https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial in Chrome and Firefox, it works as expected.

But in IE 11, after post a new comment, the new comment will flash for a second at the bottom, then it disappears. Refresh the browser window, the new comment does not show.

When close all IE windows, and open a new process of IE, the new comment will show.

Launch developer tools will also show the new comment.

Also similar issue repro in https://github.com/i-like-robots/react-tube-tracker.
So it's not specific to the code.

Repro in different machines. So it's not specific to machine configuration.

Comment: This would be better logged as an issue on the github site.

Comment: good idea. logged an issue other there: https://github.com/reactjs/react-tutorial/issues/33

Answer (score 2):

It's IE's problem with http cache. Added Cache-Control:no-cache in the server response solved the problem.